# Load content on specific pages using hook_init in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a `hook_init` in a module that needs to be executed only on specific pages.
Currently, the `hook_init` is being executed on every page load.

Question:

1. is `hook_init` the correct way to proceed?
2. if not what would be the correct option to perform page specific operations using my custom module?
3. using `hook_init` and then verify the URL of the page. Depending on the match I could execute my condition?

Comment: What would you like to do with this hook? Hook init is useful to define variables and load styles or scripts before the page is rendered. You can filter by url using drupal_get_path_alias: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7

Comment: in my case, i am using it to define and initialize variables that are used later in the page. so i should proceed with hook_init and drupal_get_path_alias ?

Comment: Yes, remember that hook_init not run in cached pages.

Comment: If your site has cached pages, you should use hook_boot, but I do not recommend this

Comment: just did a quick reading up on hook_boot. and yes there is both a cached and uncached version of this page if i have understood correctly. But then can i invoke drupal_get_path_alias from within hook_boot?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you can not use this function :( . You would try it in your Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid using hook_init or boot whenever possible. 
These hooks are executed on all pages and for me, even a path mask match is a pain for performance.

If you want to add java scripts or css to a page, **using hook_init or boot is wrong**. 
hook_init is not executed on cached pages. To add assets, implement hook_page_build and add them in using `#attached` property.

To initialize variables available in templates, implement a preprocess hook.

I'm not saying hook_init is bad. Many modules add their assets using that hook. But since Drupal 7, almost everything are render able arrays and can be altered until it reached very last stage that you can alter, adjust variables, etc.

Comment: thanks for the info. i ll have a look into the hook_preprocess. But just to be clear, my module just performs operations based on certain conditions and the results are assigned to variables to be used after the page loads.